# I'm in love with somebody

Tags: prepositions

I'm in love **with** somebody.

Does "with" modify "am" or "in"?

Context: I'm angry at myself. "At" modifies "angry". I will be an adult in the future. "In" modifies "be". What about "I'm in love **with** somebody?

Comment: prepositional phrase is what it is.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you, but why are there too many downvotes?

Comment: Possibly people downvoted because the question is based on a severe misunderstanding (that 'with' modifies words).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, and that's why the question should not be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"with" doesn't modify anything.  It heads a prepositional phrase "with someone".  This prepositional phrase identifies the person you love.

Prepositional phrases have lots of roles.  They add extra information to the sentence. Perhaps the best know is "locative" : Prepositional phrases like "in France" tell you where something happened.  But that is not the only role.

The meaning of "with" is to include an additional person in the the action.  So you say "I played tennis with Jane." to mean "Jane and I played tennis.  Likewise "I'm in love with Jane" means "Jane and I are in love", or perhaps "I love Jane". (Neither "I'm in love with Jane" nor "I love Jane" imply that Jane loves me."

I don't agree with your analysis of "I'm angry at myself" and "I'll be an adult in the future."  In both cases, the preposition doesn't modify anything.  The first prepositional phrase "at myself" indicates the target of your anger.  The second phrase is a time phrase, indicating when the state "I'll be an adult" will happen.

Comment: This is not the way I read it. For me, *in love with* is not a symmetric relation: it’s possible for John to be in love with Jane without her also being in love with him. In that sense, it **is** parallel to *angry at*. And a third phrase that bridges the two is *upset with*. Now, if you leave out the *with* and make it plural, *John and Jane are in love* implies *with one another*, so each is indeed the object of the other’s affection.

Comment: I agree, however I think this is a detail rather than the main point, which is that "with" isn't an adjunct of "in" or "am".